# Display all intro.js tour steps at once

Tags: intro.js

Is there is a way to display all the tooltips for the steps of an `intro.js` tour at once instead of stepping through every time?

Answer (score 1):

You could use Chardin.js instead.

Comment: It has very limited functionality. Any other way of doing it in intro.js. Dont want to be using two libraries.